# Is it possible to run xamarin ios uitest through visual studio on mac?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, parallels, uitest

I know you cannot run xamarin ios uitests on windows as the xamarin support site says, but is it possible to run it through parallels locally on a mac? I know you can run/build/debug with the xamarin.ios extension but does that apply to xamarin uitests with the simulator as well?

[Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/)

Thanks